# Translation in .yml with optional parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I want to make a translation `my_translation` with an optional parameter. For example:

```
> I18n.t('my_translation')
=> "This is my translation"
> I18n.t('my_translation', parameter: 1)
=> "This is my translation with an optional parameter which value is 1"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 37):

Yes, definitely. You just write the translations like this:

```
my_translation: This is my translation with an optional parameter which value is %{parameter}
```

Is the parameter really optional? In above translation, you have to provide all parameters.

UPDATE: Sorry, I answered too soon. I don't think it's easy to do. Maybe the easiest way is like this:

```
> I18n.t('my_translation1')
=> "This is my translation"
> I18n.t('my_translation2', parameter: 1)
=> "This is my translation with an optional parameter which value is 1"
```

Comment: Yes, it's optional. I want it to change depending if the parameter is present or not. Like in my example above.

Comment: Instead of being present or not, can the parameter always being passed? This way it'll be possible to do it with pluralization. BTW, are those values numbers?

Comment: No, it's a title of a report. I want to pass a date so it could be "My report on %{date}" if the parameter is passed or just "My report" if it's not.

Answer (score 19):

I would say it is possible, though not recommended.  You have two completely separate strings, based on your comments in @Yanhao's answer, and I would say they should be two separate entries in your yaml file:

```
report_name: My report
report_name_with_date: My report on %{date}
```

Since the existence of the `date` determines which string to display, you could perhaps test for its existence in in the `params` hash in a controller method, assign the title to a variable, and then use it in a view.  Perhaps something like:

```
report_date = params[:report_date]
if report_date && report_date.is_a?(Date)
  @report_name = I18n.t('report_name_with_date', date: report_date.to_s)
else
  @report_name = I18n.t('report_name')
end
```

If you want behaviour exactly as you have described, you'd need two yaml entries anyway, *and* you'd have extra convolution, *and* you'd be doing a I18n no-no by creating a string by concatenating two strings together, which assumes a fixed grammatical sentence structure (not to mention this drives translators up the wall):

```
report_name_with_date: My report%{on_date}
on_date: on %{date}
```

with code something like this:

```
report_date = params[:report_date]
if report_date && report_date.is_a?(Date)
  on_date = I18n.t('on_date', date: report_date.to_s)
  @report_name = I18n.t('report_name_with_date', on_date: " #{on_date}")
else
  @report_name = I18n.t('report_name_with_date', on_date: nil)
end
```

So, in summary, I'd say go with two separate whole strings, like in the first example.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way i did it!

1. First set my translation

   ```
   I18n.t('my_translation', parameter: optional_parameter)
   ```
2. Check if value is nil

   ```
   optional_parameter = value.nil? "" : "with an optional parameter which value is #{value}"
   I18n.t('my_translation', parameter: optional_parameter)
   ```

   - if value is nil   `=>"This is my translation"`
   - if value is 1 `=> "This is my translation with an optional parameter which value is 1"`

Comment: where's the translation of "with an optional parameter which value is " come in?....

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `number` as an optional argument, `Rails` provides a better way to handle it.

e.g.

```rb
  invoice:
    zero: "Great! You have no pending invoices."
    one: "You have only 1 pending invoice."
    other: "You have %{count} pending invoices."
  
  >> t("invoice", count: 0) 
  => Great! You have no pending invoices.

  >> t("invoice", count: 1)
  => You have only 1 pending invoice.

  >> t("invoice", count: 5) 
  => You have 5 pending invoices.
```