# How to set up yaml references within a single .yaml file?

Tags: javascript, html, yaml, jinja2

I have inherited a large number of .yaml files that contain an attribute like this:

```
our_price: Our price is just <sup>$</sup><span class="amount">99.95</span> this month
```

Now, the client wants to be able to take our_price, add some taxes and fees, and display a total price in the jinja templates.

What I'd like to do is add a new attribute, so it looks like this:

```
simple_price: 99.95
our_price: Our price is just <sup>$</sup><span class="amount">simple_price</span> this month
```

I've tried using aliases, but it seems they only work as the entire value of the node.

Is there a way to set this up in YAML, or a way to pull out just the float from the our_price string in jinja2?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know anything about jinja, I think your question is conceptually similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13055753/567863).

The short answer is, you can't do string interpolation in YAML the way you/your client wants to.  I believe you'll have to pass in the `simple_price` value to the `our_price` value from the view file (or jinja equivalent), and change the YAML entry to something like:

```
simple_price: 99.95
our_price: Our price is just <sup>$</sup><span class="amount">%{simple_price}</span>
```

Or, using aliases and anchors, you can bring back the price and string as an array to the view, and then join them into a single string there:

```
simple_price: &simple_price <sup>$</sup><span class="amount">99.95</span>
our_price: 
  - Our price is just
  - *simple_price
```