# Use another I18n key in an I18n interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, interpolation, rails-i18n

This might be I18n-ception but lets say I have an `en.yml` file as below

```
en:
  my_var: Foo
  my_message: "This is a message where I'd like to interpolate I18n's %{my_var}"
```

Is there a way to indicate to I18n that `%{my_var}` should be the `my_var` key in `en.yml`?

I know I could accomplish it by doing something like

```
I18n.t 'my_message', :my_var => I18n.t('my_var')
```

but I was hoping I18n has a way to self reference keys.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is actually a pretty common question, but the short answer is no, this isn't possible unfortunately :(

Comment: This is the correct answer, unfortunately.  For your reference @Aaron, see SO questions/answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13055753/567863) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13937891/567863).

Comment: Is this answer actually right? Still having no way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Currently I struggle for it... And finally I create a custom yaml type.

in init section.

```
Psych.add_builtin_type('i18n') { |_type, value|
  ->(_key, _options) do
    value.gsub(/%\{([\w.]+)\}/) do |match|
      key = $1.to_sym
      if I18n.exists?(key)
        I18n.t(key)
      else
        match
      end
    end
  end
}
I18n.reload!
```

in en.yml

```
en:
  my_var: Foo
  my_message: !!i18n "This is a message where I'd like to interpolate I18n's %{my_var}"
```

`!!i18n` apply custom builtin type.

Comment: Very cool! I'll have to read up on Psych and `add_builtin_type` to fully understand the performance characteristics but this looks like a great patch.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, maybe it is not a so straight solution to call twice from the view to the translation

```
<%= t("my_message", my_var: t("my_var") ) %>
```

but gives you the flexibility to call with a variable

```
<%= t("my_message", my_var: t("my_#{$item[:slug]}") ) %>
```