# How do I set a custom email subject in a custom Devise email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise in a Rails 3 application to create accounts.  I have different types of users, so I want to send out custom password recovery emails based on the type of user.

I am able to send the custom email, I haven't found a way to set custom headers on that email.  I am particularly interested in setting the subject of the email.

I have done the following:

- Created a custom Devise mailer with a custom method inside.  This method calls devise_mail with parameters.  In this case, the custom mailer is called "reset_partner_instructions".  I am able to call this mailer and successfully send an email from my User model.
- Created a custom email view template which is successfully being called from `devise_mail`.

My custom mailer looks like this:

```
class AccountMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within application_helper.
  def reset_partner_instructions(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :reset_partner_instructions, opts)
  end
end
```

The problem is that the subject of the email is always "Reset partner instructions".  I believe Devise is generating this title from the name of the mail template.

In this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer, they call the following code:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
  headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
  super
end
```

Since I'm calling "devise_mail" directly, I'm not seeing how to pass the headers intoto the mailer.  Is there a simple setting or method I can use to set the email subject?

Answer (score 23):

See [devise helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L28)

```
class AccountMailer < Devise::Mailer


   def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
    headers = {
        :subject => "Subject Here"
    }
    super
  end

end
```

Or you can change it in `devise.en.yml` file in intilizer directory

And set your own subject

```
mailer:
    confirmation_instructions:
        subject: 'Confirmation instructions'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I ended up just creating a custom mailer.  I felt it was a much cleaner solution, and I didn't have to override anything Devise was doing.

Comment: But how can I pass a variable to Locale? Like I want to use the first name in the subject.

Comment: @AmmarShah take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13954066/1297435)

Answer (score 7):

It is very old question, it may be helpful still for you are others,

for custom subject:

1. create a file **config/locales/devise.en.yml**
2. add the content like this as shown below, make sure you do the **indentation properly with 2 spaces as you do in database.yml file**.

   `en:
     devise:
       mailer:
         confirmation_instructions:
           subject: 'Verification subject here'
         reset_password_instructions:
           subject: 'Reset password subject here'`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but still comes up at the top of search and I was able to solve this by setting `opts[:subject]` instead of setting the header:

```
# https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:subject] = ...
    opts[:from] = ...
    opts[:reply_to] = ...
    super
  end
end
```

And in `devise.rb`:

```
  config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I should just use ActionMailer for this task.  Devise wasn't giving me extra functionality, and since I was trying to generate a custom mailer, i could do that outside of Devise.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to set up a custom mailer or override Devise's `confirmation_instructions` method.

Devise let's you pass in optional parameters to the `confirmation_instructions` method that will get merged with Devise's default options (the `opts` hash gets passed through to Devise's  [headers_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L28) helper).

So you could use the following code to send confirmation instructions with a custom subject:

```
Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(user, {subject: "Custom Subject"}).deliver
```

Comment: When I use your solution, it does not work at all, When I set           # template_path: "/app/views/shared/users/mailer",
          # template_name: "mytest.html.erb"
, rails throws this error: Missing template /app/views/shared/users/mailer/mytest.html.erb with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "/app/views/shared/users/mailer". Although the file is there already.