# Use a locale translation inside of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

Is there a way to do something like this

```
en:
  name: "Jimmy"
  sentence: "my name is %{name}"
```

this way I would be able to construct translation which are built on each other and are more dynamic so I could do

```
es:
  name: "Inigo Montoya"
  sentence: "My-o name-o es %{name}" (still working on the spanish part)
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this in the way you want in YAML.

See the [Passing variables inside rails internationalization yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13055753/567863) thread for an answer to a question nearly exactly the same as yours.