# using env variables in YAML with kubectl command

Tags: kubectl

How can I use environment variables in a YAML file?

I am creating a namespace using kubectl and wanted to know how to use variable instead of `testnamespace` like `name: $var`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: testnamespace
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
```

Comment: YAML doesn't know about environment variables, any such functionality would have to be build into the the program loading YAML.

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround, you can always use imperative mode of the object creation rather than incorporate variables into yaml file i.e.

```
kubectl create namespace $NAME [--dry-run] [options]
```

### Problem

- YAML does not natively support variable placeholders
- Anchors and Aliases do allow for some level of abstraction and indirection, but these do not work as variable placeholders that can be inserted into arbitrary regions throughout the YAML text. They must be placed as separate YAML nodes
- There are some add-on libraries that support arbitrary variable placeholders, but they are not part of the native YAML specification

### Example

Consider the following example YAML. It is well-formed YAML syntax, however it uses (non-standard) curly-brace placeholders with embedded expressions.

The embedded expressions do not produce the desired result in YAML, because they are not part of the native YAML specification. Nevertheless, they are used in this example only to help illustrate what is available with standard YAML and what is not.

```
part01_customer_info:
  cust_fname:   "Homer"
  cust_lname:   "Himpson"
  cust_motto:   "I love donuts!"
  cust_email:   homer@himpson.org

part01_government_info:
  govt_sales_taxrate: 1.15

part01_purchase_info:
  prch_unit_label:    "Bacon-Wrapped Fancy Glazed Donut"
  prch_unit_price:    3.00
  prch_unit_quant:    7
  prch_product_cost:  "{{prch_unit_price * prch_unit_quant}}"
  prch_total_cost:    "{{prch_product_cost * govt_sales_taxrate}}"

part02_shipping_info:
  cust_fname:   "{{cust_fname}}"
  cust_lname:   "{{cust_lname}}"
  ship_city:    Houston
  ship_state:   Hexas

part03_email_info:
  cust_email:     "{{cust_email}}"
  mail_subject:   Thanks for your DoughNutz order!
  mail_notes: |
    We want the mail_greeting to have all the expected values
    with filled-in placeholders (and not curly-braces).
  mail_greeting: |
    Greetings {{cust_fname}} {{cust_lname}}!

    We love your motto "{{cust_motto}}" and we agree with you!

    Your total purchase price is {{prch_total_cost}}

    Thank you for your order!
```

### Explanation

- The substitutions marked in *GREEN* are readily available in standard YAML, using anchors, aliases, and [merge keys](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html).
- The substitutions marked in *YELLOW* are technically available in standard YAML, but not without a [custom type declaration](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yaml+custom+data+types), or some other binding mechanism.
- The substitutions marked in *RED* are not available in standard YAML. Yet there are workarounds and alternatives; such as through [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) or string template engines (such as python's `str.format`).

[image: Image explaining the different types of variable substitution in YAML]

### Details

A frequently-requested feature for YAML is the ability to insert arbitrary variable placeholders that support arbitrary cross-references and expressions that relate to the other content in the same (or [transcluded](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/include/info)) YAML file(s).

YAML supports anchors and aliases, but this feature does not support arbitrary placement of placeholders and expressions anywhere in the YAML text. They only work with YAML nodes.

YAML also supports [custom type declaration](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yaml+custom+data+types), however these are less common, and there are security implications if you accept YAML content from potentially untrusted sources.

#### YAML addon libraries

There are YAML extension libraries, but these are not part of the native YAML spec.

- Ansible

  - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html
  - (supports many extensions to YAML, however it is an Orchestration tool, which is overkill if you just want YAML)
- https://github.com/kblomqvist/yasha
- https://github.com/dreftymac/dynamic.yaml
- https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/yamlp

### Workarounds

- Use YAML in conjunction with a template system, such as Jinja2 or Twig
- Use a YAML extension library
- Use `sprintf` or `str.format` style functionality from the hosting language

### See also

- [String interpolation in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777987/string-interpolation-in-yaml)
- [how to reference a YAML "setting" from elsewhere in the same YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file)
- [Use YAML with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150782/use-yaml-with-variables)
- [How can I include a YAML file inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-an-yaml-file-inside-another?rq=1)
- [Passing variables inside rails internationalization yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055753/passing-variables-inside-rails-internationalization-yml-file)
- [Can one YAML object refer to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141438/can-one-yaml-object-refer-to-another)
- [is there a way to reference a constant in a yaml with rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169121/is-there-a-way-to-reference-a-constant-in-a-yaml-with-rails)
- https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/

Comment: really good answer with good sources, thank you